Menu item on a category
I read your post on how to create a menu based on category, but it displays all the posts in their entirety instead of just get the title as a link. 

I now have only some 12 posts in a category but when I will have some 200 of them, it will be very cumbersome to have to scroll through them all. How can I do that ?

Your question is incredibly unclear. "Your post" - whose post?
